# Where can I read about real characteristics of lord Indra?

Tags: scripture, indra

In which scripture, I can read the behavior, mind-set or characteristic of lord Indra. All the TV series I have seen so far depicted lard Indra as a jealous, selfish and practicing debauchery. In fact, sometimes his crimes are as far as to be malevolent to saintly beings e.g. having unsolicited coitus with sati [Ahalya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahalya) the wife of the sage Gautama Maharishi. The list of his vice is endless and I guess, at least in the pop-culture TV series he is depicted like a self centered hubris lecherous man.

If, I am not wrong, then all those people who have taken or will take the position of Indra had in their past lives completely surrendered to Godhead through their penances. Also, during his time as Indra, the then Indra has seen Trimurty: Brahma, Vishnu, and Maheshwara, so, that has its own benefits in spiritual realm in certain respects because a common men can't see them so easily.

Then, my question is, why such self realized being retrogresses to such a low extreme? Or, it is true that he has such qualities but in TV serials it is shown with low standards?

Comment: Not a forum for whether TV writers follow scripture. Please direct your questions on the authenticity of TV characters to the writers themselves.

Comment: Mr. Monk he is not asking characters based on TV serials. Person is asking authentic scripture from where he can read about indra dev. He doesn't ask about indras guna based on TV

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Swami ji here is the first line in the description section **"In which scripture, I can read the behavior, mind-set or characteristic of lord Indra".**

Answer (score 4):

One of the best hymns describing the characteristics of Bhagavan Indra is found in Rig Veda.

[Rig Veda 2.12](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv02012.htm)

> HYMN XII. Indra.

> 1. HE who, just born, chief God of lofty spirit by power and might became the Gods’ protector,
>    Before whose breath through greatness of his valour the two worlds trembled, He, O men, is Indra.

> 2 He who fixed fast and firm the earth that staggered, and set at rest the agitated mountains,
> Who measured out the air's wide middle region and gave the heaven support, He, men, is Indra.

> 3 Who slew the Dragon, freed the Seven Rivers, and drove the kine forth from the cave of Vala,
> Begat the fire between two stones, the spoiler in warriors’ battle, He, O men, is Indra.

> 4 By whom this universe was made to tremble, who chased away the humbled brood of demons,
> Who, like a gambler gathering his winnings seized the foe's riches, He, O men, is Indra.

> 5 Of whom, the Terrible, they ask, Where is He? or verily they say of him, He is not.
> He sweeps away, like birds, the foe's possessions. Have faith in him, for He, O men, is Indra.

> 6 Stirrer to action of the poor and lowly, of priest, of suppliant who sings his praises;
> Who, fair-faced, favours him who presses Soma with stones made ready, He, O men, is Indra.

> 7 He under whose supreme control are horses, all chariots, and the villages, and cattle;
> He who gave being to the Sun and Morning, who leads the waters, He, O men, is Indra.

> 8 To whom two armies cry in close encounter, both enemies, the stronger and the weaker;
> Whom two invoke upon one chariot mounted, each for himself, He, O ye men, is Indra.

> 9 Without whose help our people never conquer; whom, battling, they invoke to give them succour;
> He of whom all this world is but the copy, who shakes things moveless, He, O men, is Indra.

> 10 He who hath smitten, ere they knew their danger, with his hurled weapon many grievous sinners;
> Who pardons not his boldness who provokes him, who slays the Dasyu, He, O men, is Indra.

> 11 He who discovered in the fortieth autumn Śambara as he dwelt among the mountains;
> Who slew the Dragon putting forth his vigour, the demon lying there, He, men, is Indra.

> 12 Who with seven guiding reins, the Bull, the Mighty, set free the Seven great Floods to flow at pleasure;
> Who, thunder-armed, rent Rauhiṇa in pieces when scaling heaven, He, O ye men, is Indra.

> 13 Even the Heaven and Earth bow down before him, before his very breath the mountains tremble.
> Known as the Soma-drinker, armed with thunder, who wields the bolt, He, O ye men, is Indra.

> 14 Who aids with favour him who pours the Soma and him who brews it, sacrificer, singer.
> Whom prayer exalts, and pouring forth of Soma, and this our gift, He, O ye men, Is Indra.

> 15 Thou verily art fierce and true who sendest strength to the man who brews and pours libation.
> So may we evermore, thy friends, O Indra, speak loudly to the synod with our heroes.